# How to call method every fixed period of time, given it execution time

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000 i++) {
     //call every 1000ms
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     doLongTimeOperation();
}
```

and long time operation

```
void doLongTimeOperation(){
     //Long time op
     Thread.sleep(randomInt);
}
```

I need to call this method every fixed period of time (1000). IE, if method executes in 500ms, next call should be after 500ms (500+500=1000). If method executes in 2000ms, next call should be after 0ms. How to implement it? Thanks

Comment: Look into `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is measure how long it took using System.currentTimeMillis () before and after to measure the difference. Subtract that difference from your desired wait time.

```
long start = System.сurrentTimeMillis();
// do stuff
long duration = System.сurrentTimeMillis()-start;
Thread.sleep (1000-duration);
```

Answer (score 1):

Best option is ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay method.

scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long delay, TimeUnit unit):

```
"Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given delay between the termination of one execution and the commencement of the next."
```

For further details check this link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable, long, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

No tension of calculating anything :). Note its different than scheduleAtFixedRate method. Hope it helps.

Comment: At fixed delay is the specific behavior he does not want.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you actually want is schedule at fixed rate.

> Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first
>   after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given period;
>   that is executions will commence after initialDelay then
>   initialDelay+period, then initialDelay + 2 * period, and so on.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)